# Представление decimal в C#

Tags: c#

Добрый день, нужно узнать, как хранится тип `decimal` в C#. Побитово, т.е. где мантисса, разряд и т.п.

Comment: А зачем вам, если не секрет? Вы ведь не собираетесь этой информацией _пользоваться_ в реальном проекте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вольный перевод [ответа на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294182):

> Тип `decimal` хранится в 128 битах, но используется только 102 из них.
>   Первые три 32-битных целых представляют мантиссу, в последнем 32-битном целом:
>
> - старший бит (31-й) - содержит знак числа (1 - для отрицательных чисел).
> - биты 16-23 (младшие 8 бит старшего 16-битного слова) - содержат экспоненту.
> - остальные биты должны быть равны 0.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше, чем исходники, вам ответ никто не даст. Заглядываем на [sourceof.net](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,134), видим вот что (убрал статические данные и константы, перевёл комментарий на русский):

```
public struct Decimal : IFormattable, IComparable, IConvertible, IDeserializationCallback
        , IComparable<Decimal>, IEquatable<Decimal> {

    // [...]

    // Поля lo, mid, hi, и flags содержат представление значения типа Decimal.
    // Поля lo, mid, и hi содержат 96-битную мантиссу (целочисленную часть) Decimal.
    // Биты 0-15 (младшее слово) поля flags не используются и должны содержать ноль;
    // биты 16-23 должны содержать значение между 0 and 28, означающее степень 10,
    // на которую нужно разделить 96-битную мантиссу, чтобы получить значение Decimal;
    // биты 24-30 не используются и обязаны содержать ноль;
    // и наконец бит 31 означает знак значения Decimal, 0 означает положительное
    //  значение, а 1 - отрицательное.
    //
    // ВНИМАНИЕ: Не изменяйте порядок определения полей! Нативный код в этом классе
    // рассчитывает на именно такой порядок.
    private int flags;
    private int hi;
    private int lo;
    private int mid;

    // [...]

}
```